# How do I set up rewards to account for unmanned aerial vehicle crashes?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, real-time

I am working on a project to implement a collision avoidance algorithm on a real [unmanned aerial vehicle (UAV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmanned_aerial_vehicle).

I'm interested in understanding the process to set up a negative reward to account for scenarios wherein there is a UAV crash. This can be done very easily during the simulation (if the UAV touches any object, the episode stops giving a negative reward). In the real world, a UAV crash would usually entail it hitting a wall or an obstacle, which is difficult to model.

My initial plan is to stop the RL episode and manually input a negative reward (to the algorithm) each time a crash occurs. Any improvements to this plan would be highly appreciated!

Comment: This is a bad idea. Primarily because RL takes many, many episodes which will are not practical on a real device. You're better off planning using classical MPC for trajectory generation.